# Why can't i type my user, password and server in one line on Linux MSSQL , but I can type it separately?

Tags: sql-server, linux, centos7

I'm attempting to log into my SQL Server. When I type

```
sqlcmd -S 192.000.000.0 -U SA
```

it will prompt me with

```
Password:
```

Which is dandy, I'm able to type in the password and Login to my server. But that's not what my boss wants me to do. I'm supposed to be able to type

```
sqlcmd -U SA -P password -S 192.000.000.0
```

or even

```
sqlcmd -S 192.000.000.0 -U SA -P password
```

But when I do so, it responds with

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'SA' ..
```

I also need to be able to type

```
isql -v mssql SA password
```

But then I get

```
[28000][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'SA'.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Can anyone assist me?

Some additional information

```
[mssql]
Description=Content Server MSSQL
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Database=mytestDB
Server=192.000.000.0,1433
Language=us_english
```

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.4.so.2.1
UsageCount=1
```

Comment: try double quotes around your password

Comment: There are special protections around the `sa` account. Don't use it this way. Make a different account with appropriate access.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn do you know how I would go about making a different account? It by default made it that way.

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the password contains special characters and it should be wrapped with `"`

```
sqlcmd -S 192.000.000.0 -U SA -P "password"
```

Comment: It's still giving me ```Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'SA'..
``` but yes, it does have special characters

Comment: Doest the password contain `"`?

Comment: I solved it. So the whole issue was that i had a special character. Without the special character, i'm able to login.